# sprintf warning - encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, printf

I'm using the following code to find all properties for a user and in turn delete them. My problem is that I'm getting a warning: **Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments** for each of the properties.

However, when I manually enter the **$user_id** for the delete string as **first_last%%40ourwiki.com** it works!

Seems like sprintf requires double '%' but not sure why. Is there a way to get around this? Also, I'm using the same variable for file_get_contents and this works fine.

**The Code:**

```
$user="first_last@ourwiki.com";
$user_id=str_replace(array('@', '#'), array('%40', '%23'), $user);
print $user_id;

$url=("http://admin:password@172.16.214.133/@api/users/=$user_id/properties");
$xmlString=file_get_contents($url);

$delete = "http://admin:password@172.16.214.133/@api/users/=$user_id/properties/%s";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

function curl_fetch($url,$username,$password,$method='DELETE')
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password");
    return  curl_exec($ch);
}

foreach($xml->property as $property) {
  $name = $property['name'];
  $name2=str_replace(array('@', '#'), array('%40', '%23'), $name);
  print $name2;
  curl_fetch(sprintf($delete, $name2),'admin','password');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` is a special character in [`sprintf()`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). So you have to escape all `%` before processing it, `%%` is a literal `%s`.

```
$delete = str_replace("http://admin:password@172.16.214.133/@api/users/=$user_id/properties/", '%', '%%').'%s';
```

You do not have to use `sprintf` here, you can use the concatenation operator too, like:

```
$delete = "http://admin:password@172.16.214.133/@api/users/=$user_id/properties/";
curl_fetch( $delete . $name2, 'admin', 'password' );
```